# Relation between conjugacy classes and irreducible representations?

Tags: representation-theory

I was working through an example in *Problems and Solutions in Theoretical and Mathematical Physics* (Vol 2; pg5) by W.Steeb. In this the author gets the set of conjugacy classes to be:
$$\{\{I_4\},\{U_1\},\{U_2\},\{U_3\}\}$$
the line following this is:

> Thus we have four one-dimensional irreducible representations.

I know that we have four since we have four conjugacy classes. But how is the deduction made that they are one-dimensional?

Comment: All irreducible representations of a finite abelian group are $1$-dimensional when working over an algebraically closed field.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft What do you mean by 'working over an algebraically closed field'. The group does not have an associated field (like a vector space would). Do you mean that $\rho: G\rightarrow GL(F)$ where $F$ is algebraically closed? If so could I not always choose $F$ so that it was algebraically closed.

Comment: Yes, that is precisely what I mean. I am not sure what you mean by choosing $F$ such that it is algebraically closed. $F$ is part of the definition of a representation, so you need to keep it fixed, but presumably whatever you are reading has already fixed the field to be the complex numbers, since otherwise the claims would not be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that we are working with complex representations here (as otherwise the stated claims need not be correct).

Since all the conjugacy classes are singletons, we see that the group is abelian, and it is a consequence of Schur's lemma that all irreducible representations of a finite abelian group are $1$-dimensional (in fact, the converse holds as well, but that is not important here).